# Is it natural to use normal or normally in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english, sentence-structure, word-order

Should I use the adverb or adjective in this sentence? And does it sound natural in AE?

*I ate less today than normally.*

*I ate less today than normal.*

Comment: They both sound normal to this NAmE speaker. Neither would seem out of place in conversation.

Comment: I asked more people now and one native speaker said it's unnatural to structure the sentence like that and it should be : I ate less than I normally do. Someone else said it's ok to say both and Peter also said it's unnatural and it should be 'normal' or ' less than I normally do'. There seems to be no consensus

Comment: _I ate less than I normally do_ is a more formal expression; but either of your sentences would be heard in natural speech just as they are.

Comment: You shouldn't really worry that much about what people write in comments. This is a question and answer site, not a question and comment site, as @P.E.Dant knows.  If users have something valuable to get across to the asker, they will do so in an answer. Comments are subject to deletion at any time. Even this one.

Comment: +½ @AlanCarmack because sometimes a comment contains an insight which is not sufficiently informative to warrant an answer; e.g. _Your sentences as they are would not sound out of place in normal speech._ (Or when one wishes not to provide an answer which seems even slightly contradictory to one already posted which is technically correct.) Comments seems the perfect medium for such things: their very evanescence is part of their charm!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think for the good of the site and the asker, and to set examples for new users, when someone does not wish to provide an answer then they should desist from writing a comment that, more or less,  answers the question.

Comment: Again, +½! I wholeheartedly agree that providing a fully formed answer in commentary is a bad practice of which many of us, P.E.D. included, are sometimes guilty. We all have only the benefit of the reader in mind. Yet _Your sentences as they are would not sound out of place in normal speech_ doesn't qualify as an answer, and still it's important for the Q-word to know that. Hopefully what is imparted is a combination of the answer and the advice.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you guys are talking about, but the answer ' it wouldn't sound out of place in normal speech' is exactly what I was looking for. I moved from Germany to California and I don't want to sound out of place. I worked on my accent and as far as that goes, not one knows where I'm from. The only way people can make out that I'm not from here is my sentence structure. While some people think 'less than normal' is natural, others would think I sound weird because I didn't say 'less than normally' or 'less than I normally do'.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sentence is not quite correct

> I ate less today than *I* normally *eat*.
>   I ate less today than *I* normally *do*.

would be said if you needed to use the adverb "normally".

Your second sentence is fine, the main parts being the comparison

> less... than normal
>   *less than usual (for me)*

Comment: Could you explain the difference between normal and normally in this sentence ? Because to me, it sounds like it is not talking about the amount of food, but the fashion I ate my food in, if that makes any sense. I ate less than 'normal' as in, I didn't eat how other people normally eat.

Comment: To express a different "way" of eating (the act of eating) e.g. using your hands, you might say "He did not eat his meal in a *normal way*".  Your examples talk about the "amount" of food since "less" is used.

Comment: But it's precisely the use of elision that allows for the version *less  than normally*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that Alan?

Comment: @Chris _Elision_ (see the verb [_Elide_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/elide)) is the omitting of words that are understood by the listener, but which aren't there. In _I ate less today than (I) normally (do),_ the words in parentheses are _elided:_ they aren't spoken (or written.) [**Ellipsis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) is common in every language.

Comment: Thank you! That's why it sounds so normal for me to say  ' I ate less than normally' because I know that the 'longer' phrase is ' than I normally do' but since I'm a little bit lazy in conversational English (hehe), I try to avoid wordy constructions. Germans like to pack their sentences with words to get to the point, and I try to do away with that.

Answer (score 2):

Normally is what "you" usually do.
Normal is what is "the norm" agreed by majority of people.

Using the rule above, you will realize that both sentences can make sense but will have different meanings.